# Downloading media files from Twilio in Python

Tags: python, api, mobile, twilio, mms

I'm trying to download all the media that is sent to my Twilio account and cannot for the life of me figure out how to access the actual images.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import requests
from operator import itemgetter
import json

ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxx"
AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxx"

client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)


# builds a list of messages and media uris
messages = client.messages.list(from_="+19999999999")
msgs = []
for m in messages:
    line = [m.from_, m.to, m.body, m.sid, m.subresource_uris['media']]
    line = [str(x) for x in line]
    msgs.append(line)

# with list of all messages:
msgs = sorted(msgs, key=itemgetter(0))
for m in msgs:
    # get media list for each message that has one, else catch exception
    try:
        medias = client.messages(m[3]).media.list()
        # returns Twilio.Api.V2010.MediaInstance and i'm stuck
        for med in medias:
            print client.messages(m[3]).media(med.sid).fetch()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

I am just lost and can't find any concrete examples in the documentation.  I really can't even tell if I'm close, or waaaaaaaaaaay off.  Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION** Thanks to philnash
    from twilio.rest import Client
    import requests
    import json

```
# Find these values at https://twilio.com/user/account
ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxx"
AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxx"
BASE_URL = "https://%s:%s@api.twilio.com" % (ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)


# with list of all messages:
messages = client.messages.list(from_="+1999999999")
for m in messages:
    sid = m.sid
    # get media list for each message that has one, else catch exception
    try:
        message = client.messages(sid).fetch()
        print message.body
        medias = message.media.list()
        # returns Twilio.Api.V2010.MediaInstance and i'm stuck
        for media in medias:
            media_instance = client.messages(sid).media(media.sid).fetch()
            uri = requests.get(BASE_URL + media_instance.uri).json()
            uri2 = requests.get(BASE_URL + uri['uri'].replace('.json', ''))
            with open(media_instance.uri.split("/")[-1].replace(".json", ".png"), "wb") as f:
                f.write(uri2.content)
                f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: What error are you getting from that code?

Comment: That's the thing.  I don't get an error, I just keep getting in this URI loop and never actually get to a place that I can download a photo.  No errors, just confusing.

Comment: The above code returns a bunch of MediaInstance objects: <Twilio.Api.V2010.MediaInstance message_sid=MMxxxxxxx sid=MExxxxxxx account_sid=ACxxxxxxxx>

Comment: Those objects have a uri and when I call it I get  `` {u'parent_sid': u'MMxxxxx', u'date_updated': u'Wed, 26 Apr 2017 21:20:30 +0000', u'uri': u'/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACdxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxx/Media/MExxxxx.json', u'account_sid': u'ACxxxxx4', u'content_type': u'image/jpeg', u'sid': u'MExxxxx4', u'date_created': u'Wed, 26 Apr 2017 21:20:30 +0000'}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you get the Media URI from the helper library, it is the json representation of the resource and ends in .json. To get the raw resource you need only to strip the .json extension. You can use that URL to download the image.

Comment: You put the angel in evangelist!  Thanks so much; exactly the solution!

Comment: @philnash That's not working for me. I'm using the MediaUrl with no extension and it keeps sending me xml. Can't ever get to the actual image.

Comment: Not sure what's going on for you but maybe check this blog post for better detail than I have in this answer: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/how-to-receive-and-download-picture-messages-in-python-with-twilio-mms.html