# I can't get an image sent by the user on WhatsApp using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've done plenty and this is one of the last things to get the chatbot working. I'm trying to receive an image (a selfie) from the user on my WhatsApp chatbot with no success. I'm using Python with Django.

```
@twilio_view
def visita_selfie(request):
    print('VISITA SELFIE')

    message_sid = request.POST.get('MessageSid', '')
    from_number = request.POST.get('From', '')
    num_media = int(request.POST.get('NumMedia', 0))

    media_files = [(request.POST.get("MediaUrl{}".format(i), ''),
                    request.POST.get("MediaContentType{}".format(i), ''))
                   for i in range(0, num_media)]

    print('media files')
    print(media_files)

    memory = json.loads(request.POST.get('Memory'))

    print('Memory= ',memory)


    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

At first I tried something like:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "say": "Please send me the selfie."
    },
    {
      "listen": true
    },
    {
      "redirect" : "my webhook"
    }
  ]
}
```

but that didn't work.

I got nothing on my logs and the Twilio Debugger showed me:

```
Request Inspector
- Collapse All
POST
https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/AC0de44f5c63d50ab672ae85bef67ff3bc/UA313a4235eb1ee7cc39ce2ec1781d911a/twilio-messaging/whatsapp
2019-11-12 17:54:05 UTC
400
Request
URL

https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/AC0de44f5c63d50ab672ae85bef67ff3bc/UA313a4235eb1ee7cc39ce2ec1781d911a/twilio-messaging/whatsapp

Parameters
Show Raw
ApiVersion
    "2010-04-01"
MediaUrl0
    "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC0de44f5c63d50ab672ae85bef67ff3bc/Messages/MMd9aa12480e0bebd90ace8a8d5e46cca9/Media/MEaf6ae55ca8c5b27defdef15698a182f8"
SmsSid
    "MMd9aa12480e0bebd90ace8a8d5e46cca9"
SmsStatus
    "received"
SmsMessageSid
    "MMd9aa12480e0bebd90ace8a8d5e46cca9"
NumSegments
    "1"
From
    "whatsapp:+553584311599"
To
    "whatsapp:+14155238886"
MessageSid
    "MMd9aa12480e0bebd90ace8a8d5e46cca9"
Body
    ""
AccountSid
    "AC0de44f5c63d50ab672ae85bef67ff3bc"
NumMedia
    "1"
MediaContentType0
    "image/jpeg"
Message Text
Show Raw
Msg
    "Bad Request"
sourceComponent
    "14100"
ErrorCode
    "11200"
EmailNotification
    "false"
httpResponse
    "400"
LogLevel
    "ERROR"
url
    "https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/AC0de44f5c63d50ab672ae85bef67ff3bc/UA313a4235eb1ee7cc39ce2ec1781d911a/twilio-messaging/whatsapp"
Response
Headers
X-Cache MISS from Twilio-Cache
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from Twilio-Cache:3128
X-Twilio-WebhookAttempt 1
X-Twilio-WebhookRetriable false
Content-Length 66
Date Tue, 12 Nov 2019 17:54:06 GMT
Content-Type application/json
Body
Show Raw

{
    "code": 20001,
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Missing/Invalid Parameters"
}
```

Then I tried with Collect:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "collect-selfie",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "Para que possamos identificá-lo, poderia nos enviar uma foto do rosto? (selfie)\n",
                        "name": "selfie"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": {
                        "method": "POST",
                        "uri": "https://dimep.herokuapp.com/selfie/"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I didn't work either, my log only showed me the 'VISITA SELFIE' (meaning it got to the function) when I typed in text with the collect, but the media_files was empty [].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot) [doesn't support media right now](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/known-issues#unable-to-receive-picture-messages), so you won't be able to pick up the image from the webhook like this.

Comment: So I'm only able to send images, not receive them? How can I work my way around this? I really need to receive images... do you have any ideas?

Comment: I managed to do it with this answer of yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645723/downloading-media-files-from-twilio-in-python

Thanks man!!!